# can not use auto for declaring variables

Tags: c++, qt

Why in the code below I can not use the `auto` keyword? I am not sure if this is a Qt related problem or a c++ thing?

```
#include <QFile>

void foo(const QString& path) {
    auto f = QFile(path); // Error: QFile is marked as deletet here
    QFile file(path); // works fine!!!
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a variable declaration, `auto` deduces the type from the initializer value. If you can't specify an initializer, then you can't use `auto`.

In C++17 and later, there is guaranteed [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), so `auto f = QFile(path);` will get deduced as `QFile f = QFile(path);` as expected, and then it will be optimized further to just `QFile f(path);`, eliminating any need for creating a temporary `QFile` from `path` and copying it to `f`.

Prior to C++17, that optimization is not guaranteed, it may or may not happen.  So, while `auto f = QFile(path);` will still deduce to `QFile f = QFile(path);`, that will not work if a temporary `QFile` is created from `path`, as that temporary cannot be copied into `f` because `QFile`'s copy constructor is `delete`'d to prevent copies (see [Why QObject subclasses are not copyable](https://www.cleanqt.io/blog/why-qobject-subclasses-are-not-copyable)).

So, it would seem your compiler is not performing that optimization, hence the error message, and thus no opportunity to use `auto` for declaring `f`, unless your compiler implements copy elision on function return values at least, or if `QFile` has a move constructor, eg:

```cpp
#include <QFile>

QFile getQFileFromPath(const QString& path) {
    return QFile(path);
}

void foo(const QString& path) {
    auto f = getQFileFromPath(path);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is not the `auto`. It's that you're implicitly using the copy constructor, which is not allowed for any QObject-derived class. It also would not work if you did this:

```
QFile f = QFile(path);
```

Comment: Note this will work in C++17 because there's no longer a (theoretical) copy there.

Comment: Is there anyway to use auto explicitly then?

Comment: Maybe as @chris said, if you use C++17. But otherwise, no I don't see a way.